# Using multiple AWSProfileNames simultaneously in your .Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

**Setup**
I am building a .Net application which needs to access AWS SQS and S3.

So far, I have defined the AWS credentials for a single account using AWS' preferred method ([putting them in a credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html#creds-file)).

So, my credentials file which lives at:

```
C:\aws_service_credentials\credentials
```

looks like this:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY_01
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY_01
```

And my `App.Config` file looks like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="AWSProfileName" value="default" />
    <add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="C:\aws_service_credentials\credentials" />
</appSettings>
```

This works quite well and I can initialize my clients in code directly such as:

```
var sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

**The Problem**
Now, I have been told that the S3 credentials will belong to a separate client account -- Say Client01 and the SQS credentials will belong to another account -- Client02.

These two client accounts are **not** under the same AWS account and are totally separate.

**The Question**
Is it possible to achieve this scenario using the credentials file?

I know I can create multiple profiles in the Credentials file. For eg:

```
[client01]
aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY_01
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY_01

[client02]
aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY_02
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY_02
```

But how can I switch this programmatically at runtime?

It would be great to be able to do something like this:

**AppSettings**

```
<appSettings>        
    <add key="AWSProfilesLocation" value="C:\aws_service_credentials\credentials" />
</appSettings>
```

**Code:**

```
var sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient("client02", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
var s3Client = new AmazonSQSClient("client01", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
```

My current solution in mind is to define the keys & secrets directly in a config file which I will then access programmatically and pass the values to the clients during initialization -- but I am looking to avoid that.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using the Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement.CredentialProfileStoreChain class you can look up credentials by a profile name.

```
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement;

using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.SQS;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var store = new CredentialProfileStoreChain(@"C:\aws_service_credentials\credentials");

            store.TryGetAWSCredentials("clientSQS", out AWSCredentials clientSQSCredentials);
            var sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient(clientSQSCredentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            store.TryGetAWSCredentials("clientS3", out AWSCredentials clientS3Credentials);
            var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(clientS3Credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        }
    }
}
```